# My implementation of collision detection doesn't behave normally

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I've been trying to use some simple force implementations in p5.js, I have the concept in mind but I feel like I overlooked a simple error in my code. This is my code right now:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var grav = new p5.Vector(0, 13, 0);
var bounce = new p5.Vector(0, -13, 0);
var isbounce = false;
var ymax = 0;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 400);
}

function draw() {
    console.log(ymax, isbounce);
    background(0);
    fill(255);
    ellipse(200, y, 50, 50);

    if (y < 376 && isbounce == false) {
        y += grav.y;
    }
    if (y >= 376) {
        isbounce = true;
    }
    if (isbounce == true) {
        y += bounce.y;
        if (y == ymax) {
            isbounce = false;
            ymax++;
        }
    }
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YSbakker/eLdy9cr5/)

As you can see, the object does bounce twice, but then it completely floats off the screen. I can't explain this, I looked at the console and it confirmed that it only bounced twice (setting `isbounce` to true, false and true again). What I'm expecting is that `isbounce` will be set to true everytime the object hits the ground, and to false whenever its y value reaches ymax (which decreases everytime it bounces to stimulate energy loss). I thought this was a rather easy implementation of forces, but I'm puzzled as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: you might find [this tutorial](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) on collision detection useful. The first part talks about edge collision detection. It's written for Processing, but everything should be pretty much the same in P5.js.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I appreciate suggestion, but my issue wasn't really with collision detection. I thought my issue was with my implementation of gravity, it turns out I just used a wrong operator and overlooked it. Great tutorial though.

Comment: I'm not trying to be annoying, and it's completely okay if you've moved on and don't feel like thinking about this anymore. But like the accepted answer says, your problem was definitely the collision detection code (detecting collision with an edge).

Comment: @KevinWorkman that's alright, but I think you've misinterpreted me. I have a great understanding of how collision detection works, it was a mere error in my code (I used == instead of <= at first to make sure it registered, because that seemed to be the problem at first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `if (y == ymax) {` by `if (y <= ymax) {` to make sure it does bounce at the top of the screen.